# How can I boot ubuntu 22 installed in dual with windows 11?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows

I have installed **ubuntu 22** on my HP laptop that is already running **windows 11**. I restarted the computer and selected ubuntu to make sure it was all okay, then I restarted again to run on windows, and all went also good. But since then, when I shutdown or restart the computer, it goes straight to windows without giving me the **option to choose which OS** I want to use.

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Each operating system has something called a bootloader, which is a piece of software that among other things lets you choose which operating system to boot to. In your case you have the Windows bootloader and GRUB, which is the bootloader commonly used on Linux operating systems.

If your computer is booting straight to Windows, then it is probably using the Windows bootloader, which by default does not recognize your Linux operating system. You have two options here:

1. Add Linux to your Windows bootloader, as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/adding-boot-entries).
2. Use GRUB as the bootloader instead. It should recognize both operating systems from the beginning.

Comment: Could you edit to elaborate on the steps to use grub instead of the windows boot loader? Thanks.

Comment: I actually don't remember exactly how I did this on my machine but I think [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/374349/pc-boots-straight-into-windows-10-instead-of-launching-grub) solution should work

Comment: Thanks @SaarKoren this was new to me, I tried it but the {current} boot loader is windows. I failed to add ubuntu or even the grub at  least. 
Can you edit the steps you went through?

Comment: Try the method shown [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3oQfnNhk7qU) at 10:57. I believe this is what I did.

Comment: Still not working for me here. I can only boot manually through the boot

Comment: Thanks again this link [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/374349/pc-boots-straight-into-windows-10-instead-of-launching-grub) led me to the solution. Everything look very good now.

**1.** Disable secure boot in the BIOS
**2.** Run the command prompt as administrator:
**3.** Type the following command and press enter

`bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi`

And the computer can start on the GRUB

Answer (score -2):

You have to enter the BIOS and choose which OS you want to boot into every time you reboot. If you don't do this, your computer will boot into the OS that you last used.

Comment: Thanks, this just gave me a clue. Here in the BIOS it wasn't really helping so I tried to choose in the boot, and I saw WINDOWS, BOOT and UBUNTU(was the last) so I selected BOOT and it displayed the GRUB. From there I could run Ubuntu. Now I am updating Ubuntu. I hope things will be better on the restart.

Comment: No, that’s just not right. You ‘tell’ the bios which bootable device to use … and if that’s grub (which it almost certainly is if you have Ubuntu as one of your os’s), grub will then let you select which os to boot. You certainly shouldn’t have to enter bios settings every time you want to switch os.